# ListView css class not being applied

Tags: html, css, listview, rows, alternating

I am trying to apply alternating row color to a listview.

I included the css in the header of the aspx page in case something else might be overriding it in a referenced stylesheet.

I've used the exact same method in other listviews that were written declaratively on the aspx page and they render as expected. However, this listview is bound in the cs page. It runs perfectly except it ignores any css styles applied to classes.

The HTML source it generates shows the classes are being written in to the  tag correctly. As a second option, I went the AlternatingTemplate route, again the classes were written into the HTML code successfully but still no css rendering.

Is there something about binding a listview in the cs page that overrides styles applies in the aspx page? Thanks.

**ASPX:**

```
 <style>
 .EvenRowColor{background-color:#FFF;}
 .OddRowColor{background-color: #E9F1F3;}
 </style>

 <asp:ListView ID="lvOtherAccts" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID=
    "itemPlaceHolder">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table id="ConsumptionData">
                    <tr>
                        <th id="Th1" runat="server">
                            Account
                        </th>
                        <th id="Th2" runat="server">
                            Service Address
                        </th>
                        <th id="Th3" runat="server">
                            City
                        </th>
                        <th id="Th4" runat="server">
                            Last Bill Date
                        </th>
                        <th id="Th5" runat="server">
                            Billed Balance Due
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr> 

                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>

 <ItemTemplate>
                <tr class='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Container.DataItemIndex % 2) ? "OddRowColor" : "EvenRowColor" %>'>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AcctNbr" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("acct_nbr")%>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="SvcAddr" align="left" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("svc_addr")%>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="SvcCity" runat="server" align="left" Text='<%#Eval("svc_city")%>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="BillDate" runat="server" Text='<%#DateTime.Parse(Eval("billing_date").ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")%>' />
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 50px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="Balance" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("w_bal", "{0:C2}") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>  
  </asp:ListView>
```

**CS:**

```
 String strConnString10 = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["billing_webConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con10 = new SqlConnection(strConnString10);
        SqlCommand cmd10 = new SqlCommand("SELECT landlord_nbr, svc_addr, svc_addr2, svc_city, svc_state, svc_zip, acct_nbr, billing_date, w_bal from landlord_info where landlord_nbr='" + ll_num + "'ORDER BY acct_nbr ASC", con10);
        cmd10.Parameters.Add("conn_nbr", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Session["LLNum"];
        cmd10.Connection = con10;
        SqlDataAdapter da10 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd10);
        DataTable dtLLAccts = new DataTable();
        da10.Fill(dtLLAccts);
        lvOtherAccts.DataSource = dtLLAccts;
        lvOtherAccts.DataBind();
```

**Snippet of HTML output:**

```
 <tr class='EvenRowColor'>
                    <td>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_lvOtherAccts_AcctNbr_0">209495000</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_lvOtherAccts_SvcAddr_0" align="left">266 SEAVER ST                 </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_lvOtherAccts_SvcCity_0" align="left">ROXBURY             </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_lvOtherAccts_BillDate_0">07/21/2014</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 50px;">
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_lvOtherAccts_Balance_0">$1,925.68</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class='OddRowColor'>
                    <td>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_lvOtherAccts_AcctNbr_1">209642001</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_lvOtherAccts_SvcAddr_1" align="left">47 NAZING ST                  </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_lvOtherAccts_SvcCity_1" align="left">ROXBURY             </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_lvOtherAccts_BillDate_1">07/21/2014</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 50px;">
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolderMain_lvOtherAccts_Balance_1">$571.06</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: You could do this more simply by using the CSS3 Selector for `even` and `odd` rows: `tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: :#FFF; } tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #E9F1F3; }` assuming you don't need to support < IE8

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply like below.

```
.EvenRowColor td{background-color:#FFF;}
.OddRowColor td{background-color: #E9F1F3;}
```

If the above code does not work then some other styles overwriting yours. So use `!important` keyword.

```
.EvenRowColor td{background-color:#FFF !important;}
.OddRowColor td{background-color: #E9F1F3 !important;}
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh, that did it. I wonder why the other listviews didn't require the same level of specificity. They basically have the same mark-up.

Comment: May be it got overwritten by some other styles.

Comment: Ben, I will test the nth-child method on my browsers as it does look much simpler. Thanks!